# How to generate a schema from an existing database

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using microsoft sql server management studio 2008 and I want create a brand new database with all the same qualities of my current database has, but without the data the my current database has.

For example the user.dbo has say 12 users in it with passwords and other information in it. I only want the outline of that database and not have the users.

Can someone give me the right path toward getting that outline and then applying it to a new database?

Answer (score 4):

1. From the management studio right click the database you want to script. Select Tasks > Generate Scripts and follow the wizard from there.
2. Then right click Databases and New Database to create a new database
3. Then right click the new database and New Query, in this window past the content of step 1 and click menu Execute (or F5)

Comment: How do i make a new database using that script?

Comment: Use 'create database [databasename]' to create a new database. Then use the script to create the objects

Comment: I don't see anything that says "create database", but if I right click on my server I can do "new database" and I do that. Using that option I cannot seem to use the script I saved, but only create a new one or something. Can you please be more specific. I am very unfamiliar with this software

Comment: thank you mate, easy-peasy

Comment: @keyerer, as Peter sad, use the generated script, after created a database, just replace the `USE [origin db name]` to `USE [created db name]` and thats it, the new database should look like the origin

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these steps

Goto Database>Right Click on DataBase>All Tasks.Generate SQL Scripts>
1.Show All(under general Tab)>select Scripts what you want
2.Under Formatting Tab select required formatting scrips
3.Under Options TAb select Required Security scripts and Table scripts
4.Then just click Ok and  In one Script only will be Having Database creation,Database Users,Tables,Stored Procedures,Indexes,PK,Fk,then we just need to run this Script on SQL Query Anlyzer where we wish to create New Empty Database

Comment: somewhat correct but still very blury and a bit confusing answer. sorry mate

Answer (score -1):

The title of this article does not represent the question well. For example you could create a schema on an existing database from an existing database.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question well. Actually he seems to ask *how* to *extract* the schema from an existing database (without the data).

Comment: I guess I didn't understand that from the title.